# Text line-height won't work with inline-block div container

Tags: css

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgnuL5je/).
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    Center with Red!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.div1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The red div and text are centered. But why line-height does not work. The text is not centered vertically. I think the reason might be the line-height not work in linear layout, but the parent div is block layout. How to center the red div and text both vertically and horizontally. The Text might be changed, so I do not want set them absolute position and use code like:

```
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple add `vertical-align: top` to `.div1`:

```css
.main {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  Center with Red!
</div>
```

Edit after @chead24 comment.

Comment: yes, the text is centered. but what happened to the red div? and why line-height does not work?

Comment: No problem, I will remove my answer :)

Comment: yes, vertical-align: top is perfectly done this sht. Could you tell me why? I want to know the reason.

Comment: @nich - because `vertical-align:top` breaks the alignment constraint that both the div and the text must sit on the same baseline.

Comment: No. Your `div` is currently empty. Put some text in it and then see. You don't need `vertical-align` if you have text in the inner div.